# PHP if else syntax problem, need help to correct it

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and still learning and I have come across this problem while writing a PHP page and I think there is an error at line 65, I am pretty sure the logic is fine. some mistake in the syntax I think, could you please point it out for me

The objective of this page is it will verify the entered email, checks whether present in DB farmers if present it will generate a token and insert the token in password_resets DB, then send email to the user with the token in a link.

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start(); 
// Include config file
require_once "config.php";
// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$email = "";
$email_err = "";
// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){ 
    // Validate new email
    if(empty(trim($_POST["email"]))){
        $email_err = "Please enter the email.";     
    } else{
        $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
    }    
    $sql = "SELECT email FROM farmers WHERE email = ?";        
    // Check input errors before updating the database
    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $param_email);            
        // Set parameters
        $param_email = $email;            
        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if($stmt->execute()){
            // Store result
            $stmt->store_result();      
            // Check if email exists
            if($stmt->num_rows == 1){  
                // generate a unique random token of length 100
                $token = bin2hex(random_bytes(50));     
                $sql = "INSERT INTO password_reset(email, token) VALUES (?, ?)";                    
                // Bind result variables
                if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)){ 
                    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $param_email, $param_token);            
                    // Set parameters
                    $param_email = $email;
                    $param_token = $token;   
                    if($stmt->execute()){  
                        // Send email to user with the token in a link they can click on
                        $to = $email;
                        $subject = "Reset your password on site.in";
                        $msg = "Hi there, click on this <a href=\"pwdreset-farmer.php?token=" . $token . "\">link</a> to reset your password on our site";
                        $msg = wordwrap($msg,70);
                        $headers = "From: info@site.in";
                        mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
                        header('location: pending.php?email=' . $email);
                    }
                    else{
                        echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
                    }
                }
                else{
                    echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
                }
            }
            else{
                // Display an error message if email doesn't exist
                $email_err = "No account found with that email.";
            }
            // Close statement
            $stmt->close();
        }
    }   
    // Close connection
    $mysqli->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: *i think there is error at line 65* it would help if you shared any error messages and also indicate which is line 65.  You would also benefit from indenting your code properly, this sometimes shows where matching if...else blocks are missaligned.

Comment: It would also be good if you can indicate line 65

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function close() on boolean in /var/www/html/pwdrstmail.php:78\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/pwdrstmail.php on line 78,  it is line  $stmt->close();

Answer (score 0):

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function close() on
>   boolean in /var/www/html/pwdrstmail.php:78\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n
>   thrown in /var/www/html/pwdrstmail.php on line 78, it is line
>   $stmt->close();

You are using the database object `$stmt` twice, for two database queries.

The first query is executing successfully, but the second is likely failing and returning the boolean `false` when you reassign it on the line: `if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)){...`.

The error you are seeing (quoted above) is because you are calling `$stmt->close()` after this has happened, and at this point `$stmt` equals `false`, and is no longer a database object you can close.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i have now added one more database object $stmt1 for the second query and sql1 variable to hold second query. after executing is dont see any errors in the logs. but it is not working as per logic, any guidance how to complete this assignment

Comment: You should make a new post if you have another question, that's how this site works. Some advice, though: you should narrow down where the issue is and provide as much information as possible. For instance, how far through the logic /does/ it get?